# Player going toward top left corner

Tags: java

I have this code in my game loop:

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (aPress) {
                        rotate -= rotSpd;
                        rotate = rotate < 0 ? 360 + rotate : rotate;
                    }
                    if (dPress) {
                        rotate += rotSpd;
                        rotate = rotate > 360 ? rotate - 360 : rotate;
                    }
                    if (wPress) {
                        x += (rotate < 180 ? speed : -speed) * Math.abs(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotate)));
                        y += (rotate < 270 ? (rotate < 90 ? -speed : speed) : -speed) * Math.abs(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotate)));
                    }
                    if (sPress) {
                        x -= (rotate < 180 ? speed : -speed) * Math.abs(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotate)));
                        y -= (rotate < 270 ? (rotate < 90 ? -speed : speed) : -speed) * Math.abs(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotate)));
                    }
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    } catch (InterruptedException annoyingUncheckedException) {}
                }
            }

        }).start();
```

It does what it should do: when you press A, it turns counterclockwise. When you press D, it turns clockwise. When you press W, it goes forward, and when you press S, it goes backwards. However, if I hold W and D, at first it goes in a circle like it should, but it slowly starts going in the direction of the top left corner. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is a guess, but you're losing some key presses during the 20 milliseconds you're sleeping.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc that wouldn't make sense. I am holding the key, not constantly pressing it.

Comment: How slowly it starts moving top-left? After one full circle what are the coordinates of point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would make use of the modulo operator, for a better understanding of the code overall (and perhaps it is also less error-prone).

```
if (aPress) {
    rotate = (rotate - rotSpd + 360) % 360;
}
if (dPress) {
    rotate = (rotate + rotSpd) % 360;
}
if (wPress) {
    x += Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotate));
    y += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotate));
}
if (sPress) {
    x -= Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotate));
    y -= Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotate));
}
```

Concerning your issue, [I made a quick jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoom/AumcZ/) to see if I could reproduce the problem but I cannot, so I guess this is related to the way key press (down/up/hold) events are handled. Perhaps you can try to log the set of pressed keys on each iteration and try to see If there is some kind of inconsistency.

NB : W/A/S/D keys have been replaced by UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT in my jsFiddle to minimize keyboard layout issues. I also refactored the code of the loop to reflect my logic and the [SJuan76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598289/sjuan76) answer.

Comment: I guess it was something to do with something in my code. Thanks, I guess this was the problem. I'll try to find any messed up code I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment, but for a better formatting I will use an answer.

I find this code (and the rest like it) a little odd:

```
x += (rotate < 180 ? speed : -speed) * Math.abs(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotate)));
```

The x (horizontal value) should depend of the cosinus, not of the sinus. Also, it is strange that you have to change the sign of the speed and then make the value of `sin` absolute.

Wouldn't it be better?

```
x+= speed * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotate))
```

Of course you might want to use a 0 heading that points vertically, but even that I find easier

```
x+= speed * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotate) + Math.PI/4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could dictate the behavior you want by doing something like this right?

```
if(wPress && dPress)
{
    //code for both being hit
}
```

My guess is that your current issue is caused by the fact that the speeds are not equal for a w and d press resulting in a non circular movement path.

Comment: No, it just does both wPress and dPress if both are pressed. Also, dPress doesn't actually move it, it just rotates, so it should go in a circle.